# Determining whether the path is in the rectangle [Android studio]

Tags: android, android-studio, path

I am making a drawing app using Android Studio and I accomplished to provide free drawing on canvas using a custom view. I put all paths in the list and in the onDraw method I do this:

```
for (Path path : paths) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
}
```

Now I want to provide selecting option so that user can select paths and delete them if he or she wants to... 
I will make this option by drawing a rectangle on user press and move.
The main problem here is how to determine whether a path is in the rectangle or not? It doesn't matter for me whether the path is whole in the rectangle or only part of it, both options are good for me. Any suggestions or help would be nice.

Comment: Add an `OnTouchListener` to your view and check the touch coordinates against the path.

Comment: This will check only if that particular point of the touch belongs to the path right?
But I want to make it possible to select more paths at once by pressing and dragging over the screen...

Comment: Yes, you receive updates as the user's finger moves. You have to update (re-draw) your view based on the movement of the fingers.